# How to hide / show "New Task" and "New Event"

Tags: apex, visualforce

Im a newbie in Salesforce.

We have Opportunities field name "Status" where in the sales consultant will select only "Open" and "Close".

In a Related Lists, we have a button "New Task" and "New Event". These button should be displayed while the Opportunities still Open. Hence, these buttons should be Hidden when the opportunities status is close.

[image]

Any idea how to configure it.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can not control that with a single page layout and the same record type. So you will need probably a page layout and a record type for each Status of your Oppty. Then with a workflow, assign your opportunity to the right record type when the Status of the oppty change. But to be honest not really great to have 2 recordtypes types just to not allow a user to create a task/event.

Comment: Or override the view page with a Visualforce page, though that's overkill for this.

Answer (score 1):

As Brovasi said, the only way to be able to configure this is to have separate record types and page layout for each "Status" and have a workflow field update that will update the recOrd type when status changes.

An alternative would be to have a validation/trigger written on Task/Event(again there will be 2 separate triggers/validations) that would check for the Opportunity.Status="Open" and only then allow user to create a new task/event.